# Running PHP code from a database

Tags: php, mysql

Ive got some code that runs html code from a database in order to not have to make a new file for every page that I might want to make, problem with this is that if the page contains php code it wont run, and im pretty sure you can do this with eval however it has security risks so I was trying to find some alternatives. I can paste the code if necessary. Ive got a php script that gets data from table and a main php script that gets the formatting in HTML and PHP for the data however it will just run  the PHP code as if it were strings from the database. 

 Here is an image of the code thats meant to be run from the php script :
[image: http://i.imgur.com/qx0rn7q.png] 
Here is the php code in that row 
[image]
And this is the main script that is meant to run it :
[image]

Comment: How is that database filled with PHP code? It looks like a security risk (what about [code injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection)?). Show some example -e.g. part of the database, and the code which is evaluating it!

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/eNamtjd.png , I cant think of any other way of doing it, as of right now the code doesnt work as it just prints the PHP code as a string. Oh and http://i.imgur.com/fHs5ko6.png is the code thats meant to run it but its just commented out right now as I just have the code running on the main site.

Comment: You should **edit your question** to improve it (put the code in the question, with four spaces before each line, not in outside sites) I don't see the database content (show the appropriate rows containing the PHP code).

Comment: Your provided code is very bad, and you need to read this immediately: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/from_flat_php_to_symfony2.html

Answer (score 0):

Why not make PHP functions? Like, for example if you wanted to spit out data from your databases using PHP, but not a lot of code, you can do something like... (for user profiles)

Like, you can make a funcs.php
then inside of it do:

```
function user_page($user_id){
    ?> [Create user page here] <?php
}
```

Then inside of any other file just do:

```
include 'funcs.php';
if(isset($_GET['username']) === true){
    user_page($_GET['username']);
} else {
    //if not loading user page then do something else
}
```

---

**EDIT**

Okay, I just saw your screenshot. 
To do something like that, a function would be good.

Ex:

```
function print_data($info1,$info2,$info3,$info4){
echo("<center>$info1</center><br>$info2<br>$info3<br>$info4");
}
```

then just calling the function with the $row[] information you have in your screenshot.

Like so:

```
print_data($row['email'],$row['name'],$row['username'],$row['ip_addr']);
```

Answer (score 0):

this question must be added to some "doing it wrong" list, honestly.

but, returning to your question you have 3 options, all of them more or less painful, and only one of them is right.

- to do it right: rewrite your engine or take some cms/framework. store text data in database, scripts/template on disk
- eval! (which you don't want)
- parse. (it will be very hard and slow and totally crazy)